# How to display stuff in VS Code debug console without `std::endl`?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging an app using `std::cout` to print something, nothing appears in the debug console (3rd tab, not external console). One of the exceptions seems to be the use of `std::endl`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while(true) {
        Sleep(500);
        std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; // Works
    }    
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    while(true) {
        Sleep(500);
        std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; // Doesn't work

        // std::cout << "Hello world!"; // Doesn't work
        // std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::flush; // Doesn't work
    }    
}
```

In the first example our lines appear over time, while on the second doesn't appear at all (or the console refreshes somewhere around 60 secs). I think this is a bug but I'm not sure, so what is a workaround? Maybe I have to configure something instead? I found this problem while working on something else: [C++: cannot see output in VS Code while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869567/c-cannot-see-output-in-vs-code-while-debugging)

## Edit

The problem is what to do when u wanna output something without a new line

Comment: `std::endl` is `\n` plus `std::flush`, which isn't one of the options you seem to have tried.

Comment: `\r\n` should flush automatically, however this is an implicit contract with the OS. Just call `std::flush`.

Comment: @MSalters the question mentions that `std::flush` doesn’t work.

Comment: @sturcotte06: `std::cout` is defined by C++, not the OS. There's no reason to assume `\r` would flush. For instance, on Windows you expect `std::cout` to call `WriteFile` on `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`. And `WriteFile` will obviously not translate `\r` to a flush. That would break Windows' CRLF end-of-line convention

Comment: @ColeJohnson: True, and it should. But that was a flush after a `'!'`, not after a `'\n'`

Comment: @MSalters Ah yeah maybe, I know that in POSIX C it flushes automatically on end-of-line, I thought Windows had the same behaviour (legacy from command line era).

Comment: @sturcotte06 "in POSIX C it flushes automatically on end-of-line" that's not really true.

Comment: Related topic but different approach, I use my own `hack::dout` ostream which is implemented in terms of [`OutputDebugString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa).  Works well for my ASCII output, if you have Unicode needs there might be some caveats.

Comment: I added an edit to the question. Nothing mentioned in the comments satisfy the problem

Comment: `std::flush` works for me, not sure what's the problem with your set up. What window are you looking at? If at "debug console", that's the wrong one. You need "terminal".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. , `DEBUG CONSOLE` is the right one, I'm sure of that, as `TERMINAL`  shows building stuff. I'm using a `launch.json` to debug my code. `std::flush` does not have any effect without `\n`. I need to be able to get stuff on the console without forcing a line end, and without using an external console (because the later one doesn't make sense)

Comment: In my setup debug console shows debugger messages and terminal shows build messages *and* program output  Not sure why you would have it any differently. Perhaps you use Windows, which is an OS with a lot of inexplicable quirks and bugs. That could explain why it behaves weirdly for you.