# Compiling a C++ program with a command-line command or through VS Code does not run properly unless libstdc++-6.dll is present

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The situation is is a problem in compiling and running C++ programs with MinGW on Windows, in VS Code or compiling from the command line in `cmd`.

The first example writes "Hello" to the standard output.

The second example runs and finishes but writes nothing.

The difference between the two examples is merely declaring a string in the second example.

When I compile the second example with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, it runs properly.

**UPDATE** I discovered that when I copy `Z:\Software\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll` to the same directory as my source, it works, both when compiling through the VS Code default build task and when compiling from the command line.

Example #1 (runs properly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
int main()
{
    // std::string str;
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Example #2: does not produce any output when run. Except in the case of compiling after copying `libstdc++-6.dll` to the same directory as the source.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

I have compiled the two examples with g++ on the command line and also through a default build task in VS Code.

First, the command line used to compile the two programs is

`g++ my_program.cpp -lstdc++ -o my_program.exe`

Second, the `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "Z:\\Software\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: Z:\\Software\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No worries about few comments. Code should comment itself. I'd use more descriptive variable names, though.

Comment: In Visual Studio, how did you add the program code? If you just copied and pasted in the file, VS will ignore it until it's formally added to the project. Try adding some complete, not-compliable garbage (<snark>`#include<bits/stdc++.h>` should do the job</snark>) into the file and see if the build fails.

Comment: what does the debugger do

Comment: @user4581301 It WORKED in Visual Studio. Running the program produced the expected output. Running the Visual Studio Code build produced no output. Of course I set up a project. I used the term "copied" to emphasize that it's the  same exact code.

Comment: Can you try temporarily making the second dimension of the `r[26][1501]` array smaller (e.g. `r[26][2]` instead?).  If that allows the program to at least print "Hello", it would suggest that something in VSCode doesn't like the large array.

Comment: if it works in visual studio and doesn't work in vscode then it is a vscode config problem - but that means we need to see the tasks.json file

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for the idea. I posted the  `tasks.json`.

Comment: Can you check the code is compiled with `-mconsole` and not `-mwindows` (try adding the former to your args)? The latter disables any console output or input, and is meant for GUIs. I believe the default shoulds be `-mconsole`, but it may be different in your tasks.  Not sure why this would fail, as it should default to console, but my MinGW setup in MSYS2 compiles and runs this perfectly fine.

Comment: Is it because you forgot to `#include <string>`?

Comment: Seems to work fine under g++ on Linux.  What version of g++ are you using in mingw?

Comment: Coding C++ in VS code is worst sometimes.. It doesn't compile properly if I add too many custom headers.

Comment: @phord String comes along with `<iostream>` in the Windows library. Adding `#include <string>` has no effect.

Comment: @susil95 What platform are you on? On Mac it works perfectly out of the box, although I've only written a small range of types of programs. Even the debugger works.

Comment: if this is a competitive programming problem you should not be using `std::`, instead do `using namespace std;` It's one of those micro-optimizations that everyone uses

Comment: Can you try the compilation manually with the same command (i.e. `Z:\\Software\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe source.cpp -o out.exe -g`)? This should not change anything, but if it doesn't fail with only this then something is very off with your vscode install.

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/262Try redirecting the output to a file. If there is still nothing, then this might not be the issue, but it is worth a shot

Comment: @Lala5th I tried both of your suggestions and it didn't work either way.

Comment: What is the return code of the compiled executable?

Comment: Can you add one of those minimal example programs to your question? Does a main function that does nothing but declare a single string variable also show the issue? Does this only happen for `std::string` but also for other types from the std like `std::vector`?

Comment: Please provide example input, so we can run this program.

Comment: I think you're simply observing the different outcomes you get when you have undefined behavior. We will not be able to reproduce or debug this if you don't provide the input file.

Comment: When I feed some input to it which looks for me ok, address sanitizer is happy https://godbolt.org/z/abPEx91T6 .  As soon as input data are invalid serious errors are reported: https://godbolt.org/z/qr5h5z7Kz

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example and an awkward workaround we found.

Comment: @composerMike From your awkward workaround, it sounds like your problem is simply that you have a .dll version mismatch somewhere.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell#Incompatible_versions

Comment: If the program won't run unless you copy the needed DLL's to the same directory then the directory with the libraries is not in the `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or a variation of these names

Answer (score 2):

Often when people can't find the output to a program in VSCode, it's because they're looking in the wrong tab. This happens [fairly often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869567/c-cannot-see-output-in-vs-code-while-debugging).

When you run a program in VSCode using F5 (or the "Start Debugging" command), the active tab switches to Terminal.

But, when you're in debugging mode, output will be shown in the "Debug Console" tab (the tabs could do with better names).

Here's your programming running in VSCode. Note that output at the bottom:

[image]