# C++ output not appearing on VScode Terminal (remote ssh debugging) POSSIBLE DUPLICATE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

POSSIBLE DUPLICATE [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869567/c-cannot-see-output-in-vs-code-while-debugging)

What differs is that the answers there don't have much to do with the problem.

Classic print-statements don't show up during remote debugging of raspberry pi until termination of the program. Tested with `std::out` and `printf()`. After crossing `return 0;` all statements get printed at once. Running VScode insiders 1.60.0 on a Win10 machine, ssh-connection to raspberry pi 4

my `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "preLaunchTask": "cmake",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "./build/${workspaceFolderBasename}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText"
        }
    ]
}
```

my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558&WT.mc_id=iot-0000-dglover
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmake",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
            },
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "--build",
                "${workspaceRoot}/build",
                "--config",
                "Debug",
                "--target",
                "all",
                "--",
                "-j",
                "6"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

example to reproduce:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << "Test!\n";
    printf("now in C\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        std::cout << i;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output at breakpoint:

```
Running executable

Breakpoint 1, main () at /home/pi/Workspace/learn_cpp/programs_jakob/main.cpp:11
11          std::cout << i;
```

Output after exit:

```
Running executable
Hello, world!
Test!
now in C
0123456789
[Inferior 1 (process 6916) exited normally]
```

Any suggestions?

### 1. EDIT:

Suggested by @molbdnilo, explicitly flushing works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << "Test!\n";
    printf("now in C\n");
    std::cout.flush();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //breakpoint

        std::cout << i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Running executable
Hello, world!
Test!
now in C

Breakpoint 1, main () at /home/pi/Workspace/learn_cpp/programs_jakob/main.cpp:10
10      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly flushing standard output?

Comment: @molbdnilo just tried and edited the post. It works, thank you. Still, why could this be necessary? Especially with cout i thought this was done automatically...

Comment: If memory serves, POSIX says that *if* standard output is a tty, it is flushed on a newline. But it's probably not a tty when you're remote-debugging.

Comment: @molbdnilo is there any way to either access the written to tty or to map the output to the (i suppose) local terminal?